# Retrieve data from a mysql table by making ajax call using jquery datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I am having a problem while retrieving data from mysql table making an ajax call. I am using jquery datatables to display the data. The code is as follows

```
var oTable;

/* Formating function for row details */
function fnFormatDetails ( nTr )
{
var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
sOut += '<tr><td>'+aData[0]+'</td></tr>';
sOut += '</table>';

return sOut;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable( {
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "../getproducts.php",
    "aData" : "POST","getproducts.php?c_name_mfac="+c_name_mfac
    "aoColumns": [
        { "sClass": "center", "bSortable": false },
        null,
        { "sClass": "center" },
    ]
} );

$('#datatables tbody tr td img').live( 'click', function () {
    var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
    if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
    {
        /* This row is already open - close it */
        this.src = "../images/details_open.png";
        oTable.fnClose( nTr );
    }
    else
    {
        /* Open this row */
        this.src = "../images/details_close.png";
        oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(nTr), 'details' );
    }
} );
} );
```

The HTML part of the code is as follows:

```
<div>                          
<table id = "datatables" class="display">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>Company Name</th>
</tr>
<thead>
<tbody>
    <?while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){               
            <tr>
                <td><img src="images/details_open.png"/></td>
        <td class="center" value="c_name_mfac"><?= $row['c_name_mfac']?></td>
    </tr>
    <?}}?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

The AJAX call is made to the file getproducts.php The code is as shown below :

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   $cname = $_POST['c_name_mfac'];

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items where c_name_mfac = $cname ");

?>
```

I am not getting any syntax error but not getting the output also.

I am a beginner in AJAX and JQUERY. Basically what I need is based on a company name I need to display all its products in the jquery Datatables. I m using the [DataTables hidden row details example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) but this dosent seem to be working for me.. Can anyone help pls.

Thanks,
NC

Comment: Can you explain the behavior you want to see, as well as the behavior you're currently seeing? I'm seeing some possible syntax errors, but knowing what errors you're receiving can help isolate the issue.

Comment: @lunchmeat317 : I have edited my code. I have a details_open.png button corresponding to each of the company name. When I click the button all the products of that company should be displayed. I am not receiving any syntax errors but I am not able to process the output.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP file is not returning any value, you should generate some JSON output, something like this:

```
<?php
   include('config.php');
   $cname = $_POST['c_name_mfac'];

   $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items where c_name_mfac = $cname ");}

   $result = new stdObject;
   $result->aaData = array();

   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
       array_push($result->aaData, $row);
   }

   header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
   header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
   header('Content-type: application/json');

   echo json_encode($result);
?>
```